# Where do Conformal maps map regions to?

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

> **Question**: How do you generally work out where a certain region $U$ gets mapped to under a given conformal map $f(z)$?

---

**Context**:

I have a region, $U$ which is a unit circle with a smaller circle removed, this circle being $|z-\frac25|\leq\frac25$. The conformal map is $f(z)=\frac{z-2}{2z-1}$. I need to find out where $U$ gets mapped to under $f$.

---

**Thoughts + attempt**:

I don't know how to work out where this region gets mapped to. I let $z=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$ and determined that any point on the unit circle gets mapped to another point on the unit circle. Also $f^{-1}(z)=f(z)$. I think this is enough to conclude that the unit circle gets mapped to itself. However this method was quite long-winded so I feel there should be a more efficient way to work this out. I am not sure how to proceed with finding where $f$ maps the other circle, I plugged in $f(z)$ in place of $z$ in the equation of the circle, and got $|z-8|=4|z-\frac12|$, but I don't know what sort of line this is. Is this method the correct way to go about it?

*PS: I don't know if I may be missing any tags, so if you feel like some tag which I haven't mentioned fits, please feel free to add it in.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your $f$ is a [Möbius transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation).  These have a number of important properties which make it easy to identify $f(U)$:

1. They are one-to-one from the Riemann sphere to itself.
2. They map straight lines or circles to straight lines or circles.

Thus all you have to do is find the straight line or circle to which $f$ maps the boundary circles of $U$, and $f(U)$ is the region between these.  Note also that a straight line or circle can be determined by three points on it.
Thus if you can show that $f(1)$, $f(-1)$ and $f(i)$ are on the unit circle, you can conclude that $f$ maps the unit circle to itself.

Comment: Ah yes, I had forgotten about those, I recall that they are quite nice to work with. Thanks :)